# Is it possible for a Macro to corrupt files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big file with a lot of Subs. One of these subs opens other files and runs the macros, which are stored in these files. Some of these files go from time to time corrupt. Without doing anything else on them. Is it possible that my macro corrupts these files? What is more, this event started to occur since the beginning of the year (2019). That never occured before that.

Comment: What version of excel are you using ?

Comment: Yes, my experience is that with `xlsm` or `xlsx` files  with big data and macros are extremely unstable (and easily get corrupted). I recommend to switch them to the binary `xlsb` format (never had a corrupted file there, and I have some rally big worksheets). • Once a file is corrupted (even if Excel tells you it repaired it) don't trust them anymore. Excel's repair never worked well for my files. • Note this is rather a personal experience than something I can proof by facts. But I run several times into issues with `xlsx/m` but never with `xlsb` (which turned out to be *much* more stable).

Comment: Thanks for the help Pен!

Comment: To anwer your question Nick, I think that started to happen some moths after Office 2016 come into use in the company (as far as I know, because I am new there). The files are used only once per month, so I guess they were used only a couple of times before this started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big are your code modules? If they are larger than 64 KB, they might cause random corruptions to the file. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1381665/is-the-64kb-size-limit-to-modules-corrupting-macros-for-excel-365) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Unfortunately, I can choose only one answer, that is why I choose the one that came first. Cheers!